# spring-xd Deployment solution?

Tags: java, spring

I would like to run Spring-XD in a distributed set up. The processing part generally takes place in any one of the available containers. If I have 100 containers, the manifest should be available in all the containers, since we do not know exactly to which container the job may be deployed. Keeping the manifest/code in all the containers is the only solution? Suggest a way so that the manifest is used only by the container where it is executed.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different things that can be deployed:

**(A)** you can deploy a stream of the form `source | ... | sink` together with a deployment manifest through the shell using `stream create (...)`. Deployment manifests allows to specify the type of nodes where the modules of the stream are expected to run.

**(B)** You can deploy custom modules, that you have written yourself to the xd-installation into the directory `xd/modules/source`, `xd/modules/sink`, `xd/modules/processor`, etc.

**If you are referring to (A):**

Deployment manifests of jobs or streams are stored as persistent nodes within Zookeeper automatically when a stream is defined. The Zookeeper process only runs on a single or some of the machines depending on your setup. See this section of the Spring XD Guide:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/#_zookeeper_overview

I would not worry about how the deployment manifest is distributed. This should simply work out of the box.

**If you are referring to (B)**

Then you can deploy your module to all nodes using a single command in the spring-xd shell by typing `module upload --file ...`.

See here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/#install-the-source-module

You could also set up your workers to read your custom module definition from a shared file system. Yet this would introduce a single point of failure (the file system).